# Still can't change my bibliography heading title!

Tags: bibliographies

I have tried to look around to see, if I could change my bibliography title, but its name is still in Danish. In Danish, the word for 'References' is 'Litteratur', but I want to change the name to 'References'. I have tried to renew the command `\refname` but nothing happens. Do you know how to fix it? I'm just using `\cite{something}` and then writing my references myself.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{extarticle}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english, danish]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage[left=0.5in, right=0.5in, top=0.8in, bottom=0.8in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[breaklinks, colorlinks,linkcolor=NavyBlue, citecolor=NavyBlue, urlcolor=Blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[all]{hypcap}
\usepackage{tikz, pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\renewcommand\refname{References}

\begin{document}
\begin{thebibliography}{depth,9}
\bibitem{Oversigtsnote 1}
\textit{Oversigts note 1} skrevet af \textit{HH}
\bibitem{Oversigtsnote 2}
\textit{Oversigts note 2} skrevet af \textit{HH}
\bibitem{Oversigtsnote 3}
\textit{Oversigts note 3} skrevet af \textit{HH}
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

This is my result:

[image]

Comment: Does `\addto{\captionsdanish}{\renewcommand\refname{References}}` solve the issue?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. Can you explain to me the syntax of this command? How does it work and why? - If it's possible to explain, it appears to be a very simple code... And maybe why my renewed command didn't work.

Comment: The case here is that you are using `babel` which, to make such things as the bibliography title language localized, uses a more elaborate structure. So, with `babel`, you need to use the `\addto{\captions<language>}{...}` to get the desired result.

Comment: you're loading `inputenc` twice, also `utf8x` is to be avoided as an unmaintained package is loaded, that has lots of bugs and other nasties. furthermore, `hyperref` should be loaded as late as possible. `titlesec` loaded twice as well. and last but not least, after some clean up, your code does produce the proper headlines for your references.

Answer (score 0):

This simple example produces a short report with Danish headlines.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,danish]{babel} %changing order of languages turns Danish headlines to English.
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{quellen.bib}
    @misc{DeutschesInstitutfurNormung.201310,
        year = {2013-10},
        title = {Information und Dokumentation -- Richtlinien f{\"u}r Titelangaben und Zitierung von Informationsressourcen (DIN ISO 690:2013-10)},
        address = {Berlin},
        publisher = {{Beuth Verlag GmbH}},
        author = {{Deutsches Institut f{\"u}r Normung}},
        language={ngerman}
    }
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

% Title Page
\title{some title}
\author{me}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
    stuff happens here
\end{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter{some title}
blabla

\section{another title}
blablabla\cite{DeutschesInstitutfurNormung.201310}

\nocite{*}
\bibliography{quellen}

\end{document}
```

`babel` can handle different languages, but the order is important, as the last given language will be loaded as the desired one. So to have English headlines change the order of languages in `babel` options.